# Porting openshift operator to kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

Is it possible to port/migrate/run an openshift operator hosted on openshift operator hub to kubernetes? Like we can migrate a pod by reading the pod specification. I am trying to migrate/run DB2 operator available on openshift operator hub on my kubernetes cluster.

Comment: Hi, Could you share the name of the operator or any link of it?  yea, it's possible to run operator on k8s

Comment: @SureshVishnoi I am looking to run `IBM® Db2U Operator` operator available on hub. Visible if you search for `IBM Db2`

Comment: I think, I have not enabled IBM Operator in my cluster, however, if you click on the operator , there must be a link to github page if its open source, then we can further investigate to bring it to k8s cluster.